# How to avoid mat-tab lazy load to reset the controls/components

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

Im using a single tab to lazy load a content with some control that depends or requires initialization such us 3rd party editor (e.g. TinyMCE).

I managed to integrate the controls, however I have this problem whenever we navigate to another tab the control keep resetting *(NOW on this case the TinyMCE editor wrapped inside another component)*.

**editor-wrapper.component.html**

```
<p>
    <editor [formControl]="editor_control"></editor>
</p>
```

**editor-wrapper.component.ts**

```
editor_control: FormControl;

constructor() {
  this.editor_control = new FormControl('Editor text... sample..');
  console.log('foo foo');
}
```

And seem like `console.log('foo foo');` keep printing when navigating back-in-fort  which means the `editor-wrapper.component` is resetting/re-initializing.

How can we avoid this? There is no option to just only lazy load the tab for a single or first time the user navigates?

Please check this **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-mat-tab-lazy-loading-problem)**

**UPDATE**

The input text was solve by using `[(ngModel)]` based on @Arash comment.

Comment: why don't you use 2 way binding for you'r ngModel , I mean instead of [ngModel] use [(ngModel)] .

Comment: Ok notify me whenever you'r update will be done.

Comment: @Arash now im done hopefully you can help.

Comment: Ok if [(ngModel)] helped please vote it

Comment: not yet, that is a partial  or one of the control i included.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `[(ngModel)]="input_str"` for tab Lazy Loading.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up of this dirty solution by listening to editor changes ***(keyup and change event)*** using `@Output` and `@Input` to maintain data.

> This will store the data to the parent level component and keep it safe
>   despite child component reset, reinitialized or even destroyed and assign it back to the child component editor content *(FormControl)* if data is not undefined.

**app.component.html**

```
<app-editor-wrapper 
    (editorChanged)="onEditorChanged($event)" 
    [editorContent]="editor_content_string">
</app-editor-wrapper>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
editor_content_string: string;

onEditorChanged(e: any) {
    this.editor_content_string = e;
}
```

Now on the editor wrapper I wrote this:

**editor-wrapper.html**

```
<editor 
   (keyup)="onTinyEditorChange($event)" 
   (change)="onTinyEditorChange($event)" 
   [formControl]="editor_control">
</editor>
```

**editor-wrapper.ts**

```
@Input()
editorContent: string;

@Output()
editorChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

editor_control: FormControl;

// Do not initialize FormControl here.
// editorContent will always undefined in this scope.
contructor() {} 

ngOnInit() {
    this.editor_control = new FormControl(this.editorContent || '');
}

onTinyEditorChange(e: any) {
    this.editorChanged.emit(this.editor_control.value);
}
```

Working **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-mat-tab-lazy-loading-temporary-solve)**